# Can not open Paypal Express Checkout in Inappbrowser in ionic App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, paypal

I am working on Paypal Express Checkout Integration with Ionic App, Paypal Client Side API is opening when I am testing on chrome on button click but not in the .apk on Android Phone. After searching a bit, I came across the InAPP Browser Cordova plugin which opens browser.

How to integrate InApp Browser with the Paypal API is the problem I have been facing as Inappbrowser requires url while Paypal API has it's own script which opens the Page on it's button click.

```
paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

    client: {
        sandbox:    'key-secret',
        production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    },

    payment: function() {

        var env    = this.props.env;
        var client = this.props.client;

        return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
                }
            ]
        });
    },

    commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

        // Optional: display a confirmation page here

        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            // Show a success page to the buyer
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
```

Inappbrowser code which opens the url is:

```
 $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('url(want to open paypal here)', '_blank', options)

  .then(function(event) {
     // success
  })

  .catch(function(event) {
     // error
  });
```

Paypal Button "I want it to open the Paypal API in Inappbrowser on this button click"

```
 <div id="paypal-button"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! I maintain the paypal-checkout integration. We don't currently have support for ionic, but this is something I'd love to explore in future. Right now we depend on https://github.com/krakenjs/xcomponent to render the checkout components, so if you're interested in figuring out what it would take to get ionic working, that'd be awesome.

The main things it would need to support is:
- Opening a window
- Sending post-messages

Comment: xcomponent paypal express checkout client side integration https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout is working on hybrid app developed for Android but not working for iOS ...

Comment: @bluepnume you may want to check this plugin I just published: [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge). It adds support to Cordova InappBrowser for Braintree's PopupBridge which adds popup window emulation to iOS and Android apps for the purpose of making PayPal payments within native app Webviews.

Comment: Cool! Any chance you could chime in over here? https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/420 -- did you have any luck getting this to work with the paypal button?

Comment: @DaveAlden After installing the cordova plugin ie cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge, I wrote  document.addEventListener("deviceReady",function(){


      window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;

      
    });  But still it is not allowing me to open the paypal page in Android Add

Comment: Not able to work with the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge. Please upvote the question, so more people try to give solution for it.

Comment: @Honey Thakuria are you using the Braintree JS SDK in the target page? This solution only works in conjunction with Braintree's payment solution which includes PayPal support.

Comment: @DavidAlden: I saw the Braintree JS SDK now, do I need to implement the server code compulsorily, can't I directly use it on the Client side API like Paypal provides  ?

Comment: Implemented the Braintree JS SDK successfully, thanks DavidAlden. @bluepnume please refer [link](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/) it worked for me finally. Please upvote the question so that other can find the solution too.